# Django ORM - Select All Records from One Table That Do Not Exist in Another Table

Tags: django-orm

Lets have 2 models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField()
    f2 = models.IntegerField()
    f3 = models.BooleanField()


class B(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField()
    f2 = models.IntegerField()
    f3 = models.DecimalField()
```

Lets have this data:

```
A(f1=rat, f2=100, f3=true)
A(f1=cat, f2=200, f3=true)
A(f1=dog, f2=300, f3=false)
```

```
B(f1=eagle, f2=100, f3=3.14)
B(f1=cat, f2=200, f3=9.81)
B(f1=dog, f2=300, f3=100.500)
```

I need to select objects from table B, that does not have similar data for fields f1, f2 in table A.

In my case it will be:

```
B(f1=eagle, f2=100, f3=3.14)
```

The following objects are not relevant, because they exist in both tables (f1 and f2 fields)

```
B(f1=cat, f2=200, f3=9.81)
B(f1=dog, f2=300, f3=100.500)
```

Is it possible to select this data using Django ORM?

I tried to find information about Sub-query, but did not find good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved in this way:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists    

a_queryset = A.objects.filter(f1=OuterRef('f1'), f2=OuterRef('f2'))

result_queryset = B.objects.filter(~Exists(a_queryset))
# B(f1=eagle, f2=100, f3=3.14)
```

reverse:

```
result_queryset = B.objects.filter(Exists(a_queryset))
# B(f1=cat, f2=200, f3=9.81)
# B(f1=dog, f2=300, f3=100.500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` with `Q` objects:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

B.objects.exclude(Q(f1__in=A.objects.values_list('f1', flat=True)) & Q(f2__in=A.objects.values_list('f2', flat=True)))
```